# Problems creating a pagedList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get to grips with asp.net MVC but am having problems creating a pagedList.  When my view uses @model IEnumerable the view displays fine but when I change it to 
@model List  or @model pagedList

I get errors in the view 
"'List' does not contain a definition for 'Category1' and no extension method 'Category1' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" and similar for every line.
Model, View and Controller (only the Index method) below.

Probably something stupid I'm doing but any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Model:

```
    namespace IssuesMVC.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
        using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

        public partial class Issue
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(85)]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            public int? AssignedTo { get; set; }

            public int OpenedBy { get; set; }

            public DateTime? OpenedDate { get; set; }

            public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }

            public DateTime? ClosedDate { get; set; }

            public int? Status { get; set; }

            public int? Category { get; set; }

            public int? Priority { get; set; }

            [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
            public string Comment { get; set; }

            public virtual Category Category1 { get; set; }

            public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

            public virtual Contact Contact1 { get; set; }

            public virtual IssueComment IssueComment { get; set; }

            public virtual Priority Priority1 { get; set; }

            public virtual Status Status1 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

View:

```
    @model List<IssuesMVC.Models.Issue>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Issues";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category1.Category1)

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.FirstName)

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IssueComment.Comment)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Priority1.Priority1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status1.Status1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OpenedBy)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OpenedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DueDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClosedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category1.Category1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact.FullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IssueComment.Comment)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority1.Priority1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status1.Status1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact1.FullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OpenedDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DueDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClosedDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using issuesMVC.Models;
using PagedList;

namespace IssuesMVC.Controllers
{
    public class IssuesController : Controller
    {
        private IssuesContext db = new IssuesContext();

        // GET: Issues
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.OpenedDateParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "OpenedBy_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.OpenedByParm = sortOrder == "OpenedDate" ? "OpenedDate_desc" : "OpenedDate";
            page = 1;
            var issues = db.issues.Include(i => i.Category1).Include(i => i.Contact).Include(i => i.Contact1).Include(i => i.issueComment).Include(i => i.Priority1).Include(i => i.Status1);
            //int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "OpenedBy_desc":
                    issues = issues.OrderByDescending(s => s.Contact1.LastName);
                    breai;
                case "OpenedDate":
                    issues = issues.OrderBy(s => s.OpenedDate);
                    breai;
                case "OpenedDate_desc":
                    issues = issues.OrderByDescending(s => s.OpenedDate);
                    breai;
                default:
                    issues = issues.OrderBy(s => s.Contact1.LastName);
                    breai;
            }


            return View(issues.ToList());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Contact.FirstName)` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the response, that syntax has solved my problem.  Can you help me to understand why?

Comment: There are 2 overloads for `DisplayNameFor()` - one that accepts `TModel` and the other `IEnumerable<TModel>` - if its not `IEnumerable<TModel>` (i.e. declared as `@model IEnumerable<T>` then it falls to the `TModel` overload - in your case `TModel` is `List<T>` and `List<T>` only contains properties `Count` etc